# Is that possible to estimate the VC dimension for GBM (or more specific XGBoost)?

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, vc-dimension

Is there any simple way to estimate the VC dimension for GBM? Or, for more specific implementation XGBoost?

XGBoost usually has large variability when training on a dataset with less than 500 samples more than 1000 features. Is there any way to estimate the model complexity of XGBoost with certain hyperparameters?